# Modifying the default WordPress .htaccess with a plugin

Tags: plugin-development, htaccess

I am developing a WordPress plugin that modifies the standard WordPress .htaccess file on the webroot folder. Currently, I inject my code inside the `# BEGIN WordPress` block, like so:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# BEGIN This is my block
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.(css|js)$
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END This is my block

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Is this a best practice? Or should I create a new `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` block for this code?

Also, is there anything else I should take note of when creating plugins that modify .htaccess?

P.S. I am adding this .htaccess block because I want to modify some parts of .css and .js files with PHP before I output them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You certainly should not be modifying the `# BEGIN WordPress` block, as this is likely to be overridden by WordPress itself.

You should create a new section *before* the WordPress front-controller. This will work just as well and keep the directives separate.

There is no need to use a `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` wrapper, in fact you *should not* use a wrapper in this instance, since your plugin would seem to be dependent on mod_rewrite being enabled. Your plugin will not function correctly if mod_rewrite is not available, so you shouldn't "fail silently" if it isn't.

*Aside:* There is also no need to repeat the `RewriteEngine` and `RewriteBase` directives. If you are hand-coding the `.htaccess` file then you would not duplicate them. However, if you are injecting this code programmatically, then you probably need to - to be sure. (Multiple `RewriteEngine` and `RewriteBase` directives are not strictly supported. The last instance in any given *context* wins and controls the entire file. For example, if you place `RewriteEngine Off` as the very last directive in the `.htaccess` file then it is `Off` for the entire file, despite there being earlier `RewriteEngine On` directives.)